# From MATLAB to C#. C# programm has lags

Tags: c#, matlab

I created some function in Matlab.
This function image grayscale picture from .mat-file.

I have this command in MATLAB.

```
figure, imshow(Image_uint8);
```

I created .dll from this function.
My small console programm on C# work, but I have big lags when I want to know point and his value of picture. It`s more than some lags.

C#

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Test11.step7();

        }
    }
}
```

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using step0;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Test11
    {
        public static void step7()
        {
            Class1 ojb = new Class1();
            MWArray output1 = ojb.step0();
            Console.WriteLine("Output ~\n" + output1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

MATLAB

```
function [pname_save] = step0()

[fname_open, pname_open] = uigetfile('*.asd','Select the .asd file');
if fname_open ~=0
    fullname = strcat(pname_open,fname_open);
    cd (pname_open);
else
    fullname = null;
end

...

    figure, imshow(Image_uint8)

    %save file
    result = regexprep(fname_open, '\.[^\.]*$', ''); 
    pname_save = [pname_open name_out];
    cd (pname_save);
...

fclose (fid); 

end
```

It`s my video.
youtu.be/dFMJLlUp2Cc

Comment: How long does same method take when run from Matlab?  It just may be the code will take time to run.  Also in Task Manager check memory used.  Often with Matlab is takes time to get memory to run methods.  You will see the memory usage will slowly get larger.

Comment: I would expect that the produced DLL will load rather large amount of wrapper or interpreter code to run, and this will take time, at least the first time it is called. If there is a small amount of code it might be better to re-implement in c#. If there is a large amount you might just have to live with it.

Comment: This scrypt work in MATLAB very fast.

I have only problem with "figure" from MATLAB(in C#).

I will create video so work my program.

Comment: The MATLAB figures require JavaVM. The first time you call this function, it’ll have to load the MATLAB interpreter and the JVM. There is a large startup time for these. There’s no way around that. I recommend that you don’t use MATLAB just for displaying an image.

Comment: Just I minimize script for forum.

Comment: It`s my video https://youtu.be/dFMJLlUp2Cc

Comment: I have Java

>> version -java

ans =

    'Java 1.8.0_121-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode'

Comment: I installed Java